# Log file not found with Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, bugs

I am using texstudio under windows to execute my `.tex` files.

When I compile the `.tex` source file and there are no errors, everything goes well and no problem appears. However, if my `.tex` source file contains any error, then texstudio will pop up an error message (of course).

The problem is after correcting the errors, texstudio will not work whatsoever I try. For example, if my `.tex` source file has no errors and works well and I write

```
$10
```

in a new line, I will get the error message

```
Missing $ inserted.
```

When I correct the error by writing

```
$10$
```

or even removing the new line, I still get the same error message.

I went to my working directory and removed the `.log` file. Then, I get the message

```
Log file not found
```

The only way I could compile my `.tex` source file again is by removing `.log` and `.aux` files and close and reopen texstudio. Obviously, I do not want to do this every time I have an error in my `.tex` source file.

Is there anyone who could help me fixing this problem?

PS
I found this answer [#614 Log file not found if -aux-directory is used](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/bugs/614/)  and I add the working directory to the Additional Search Paths in texstudio but I still get the same problem.

Comment: Any updates here? What version TXS are you using? Do you have any special characters in your file name? Does this occur only for this file, or all of your `.tex` files?